# How to parameterise karate tags in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, automation, karate

Can somebody please tell me how can we parameterise karate tags in Jenkins?

For example: We have @Regression @Smoke @Sanity tags in our feature files, so if we want to run specific tag's feature file how can we parameterise and run through Jenkins?

Comment: please refer: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bkarate%5D+jenkins+tag